# Modify a shortcut like CTRL+F in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I recreate **ctrl + f** shortcut key in my website using react?
I want to use any shortcut to trigger a filter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may help you.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {             
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {        
        e.preventDefault();         
        // trigger your filters here      
    }      
})
```

Comment: sure let me send you the record.  remember i am new to react harish      
  (Failed to compile.

./src/modules/risk/components/riskFilter.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (18:10)

  16 |             this.props.onFilterClick();
  17 |     }
> 18 |     window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {             
     |           ^
  19 |         if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {        
  20 |             e.preventDefault();         
  21 |             // trigger your filters here

Comment: anything harish!

Comment: first remove this.props.onFilterClick(); callback statement then test it. if its working without an error then the issue with scope of the "this"

Comment: i want that on click function to be shortcuted like a shortcut

Comment: this is the class ----  class RiskFilter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isShow: false
        }
    }

Comment: i think problem with logic

Comment: as per your code this statement is enough no need of state flag 
onClick={()=>{this.props.riskEssentialsLevelFilter();}}

Comment: export class RiskFilter extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isShow: false }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
                console.log('heyyyy');
                e.preventDefault();
                // trigger your filters here
            }
        }, false);
    }

    render() {
    }
}

Comment: thank you so much man you saved my day. do you like to give me any suggestion where to learn react

Comment: @harish i have another doubt ?

Comment: please go ahead

Comment: i need to sort the data in my web page. i need to add a button which will make it as ascending order and vice versa.  if (this.props.riskEventOutcomeData && this.props.riskEventOutcomeData.length > 0) {
            riskEventOutcomes = this.props.riskEventOutcomeData.map(this.createRiskEventOutcomeView);            this is the code which calls it

Comment: if you have email address i will send the data to you

Comment: harishshesi9496@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use vanilla javascript document keyup event, e.g.:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 70){ // CTRL+F
        // Put your code here
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to use something more "react" friendly take a look into https://github.com/jaywcjlove/react-hotkeys#readme